# I can't use the Ubuntu and can't dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, windows

I have 2 questions. This is the story:
I wanted to dualboot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23.10. I booted with a usb-stick in the installer and set ubuntu up as **install alongside windows**. After I did that it rebooted and I booted in Ubuntu. it worked perfectly. I saw that my SSD was found, so I could access the files. After a reboot, I saw nothing else but a empty sc reen and the control panel with the reboot and sign out option. I don't have a taskbar on the screen. My first question is: How do I fix this, so I can use Ubuntu as normal?

After I used Ubuntu, I wanted to boot into Windows 11. I pressed shift at boot, and tried my BIOS key. That did not work. I followed another question on this forum and I got a 3 second timer to access grub. But the grub menu does not open. So my second question is: How do I boot into windows 11 again.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Could you share your `/etc/default/grub` file? i think you only have to modify the `GRUB_TIMEOUT="Here you could set a timer f. e. 3 seconds"` line, after you modified this you have to run `sudo grub-update` or `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: that worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Grubs default configuration is set to skip showing menu entries, on a fresh installed Ubuntu, you have to set the `GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"` in `/etc/default/grub` to a value f. e. 3 which means this menu shows up 3s before it boots his default entry.

After changing something in `/etc/default/grub` you have to run `grub-update` or if `grub-update` for some reasons not available use `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This rewrites the grub configuration who is used at boot.